# Excel vlookup expansion

Tags: excel

I currently have an excel worksheet with three columns

```
        id      annotation     person_id
        1        yes             1
        1        no              2
        1        yes             3
```

I'm trying to reformat this on another worksheet into a table that looks like:

```
     id       1       2      3
     1       yes     no      yes
```

I'm using this

```
vlookup: =VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!$F$1:$G$10,2,FALSE)
```

where a2 is the `id` and f$1:g$10 is the range of data for that particular person.

At the moment I'm doing this per person and its tedious - there's thousands of people.  I need a way to incorporate the person_id into my vlookup so that, if the person_id in the column header matches the person_id in sheet 2 and both ids match, then insert the annotation.

Comment: Have you thought of using a pivot table? Not sure what you're trying to achieve with that.

Comment: a pivot table seems to not do what i want.  So i'm currently taking one person at a time, entering the vlookup per cell, adjusting the range to the first worksheet thats applicable to that certain person.  I can't keep doing this.  I need a way to incorporate the person_id in the vlookup.

Comment: @viper good idea ... problem here is that the data values are strings (yes / no) and Excel won't place them at the intersedction of row & column ... COUNT and SUM won't work, AVERAGE will give #DIV/0 and MIN/MAX will give "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a good candidate for an `INDEX-MATCH` formula, with a multi-condition `MATCH()` formula to account for both ID criteria. The formula below places the raw data are in `A1:C4` and the reformatted data in `E1:H2`, so you will need to change the references:

In cell `F2`, I've entered `{=INDEX($A$1:$C$4, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A$4=$E2)*($C$1:$C$4=F$1), 0), 2)}`, which yields

```
      [A]   [B]         [C]         [D]   [E]   [F]   [G]   [H]
[1]   id    annotation  person_id         ID    1     2     3 
[2]   1     yes         1                 1     yes   no    yes
[3]   1     no          2
[4]   1     yes         3
```

The relative references on `$E2` and `F$1` allow the filling of the formula across rows and columns.

To explain the formula a bit:

- In the `INDEX()` formula, the first argument `$A$1:$C$4` is the raw data "table" (array).
- The second argument searches for the row where the value `($A$1:$A$4=$E2)*($C$1:$C$4=F$1)` is *exactly* (given by the third argument, `0`) equal to `1`.

  - `($A$1:$A$4=$E2)*($C$1:$C$4=F$1)` is the multiplication of two `TRUE/FALSE` statements, which is equal to `1` when the main ID in `col A` is equal to the ID value in `E2`, *and* the person ID in `col C` is equal to the column header in `F1`.
- The final argument, `2`, is the column in the data table from which to look up the result.

  - You may want to consider using another `MATCH()` formula to dynamically identify the look-up column based on the column header; *e.g.*, instead of `2`, use `MATCH("annotation", $A$1:$C$1, 0)`.

Important notes:

- The formula needs to be entered as an *array formula* using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
- This method assumes the combinations of `id` & `person_id` are unique.

Also, note that this formula is clearer with named ranges: *e.g.* (using the suggested second `MATCH()` function instead of `2`), `{=INDEX(RawData, MATCH(1, (ID=$E2)*(PersonID=F$1), 0), MATCH("annotation", Headers, 0)}`.

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed response.  I understand exactly what you're doing.  However, I'm getting #n/a values for people who have annotated that id. Any idea why?

Comment: @user47467: My apologies. See the revised answer. (An error in cell references as I moved the "results" table & forgot to update the column references.)

Comment: @user47467: Also note that the `INDEX-MATCH` approach does _not_ require you to sort your data.

Comment: still getting #n/a error, even after remembering to set it as an array formula :/

Comment: In my example, the "results" table has the `person_id` as the row headers (`F1`, `G1`, `H1`) and the regular `id` as the row header (`E2`). If there is not an `id`-`person_id` combination corresponding to `E2`-`row 1` combination, then `#N/A` will be returned. Without seeing your data it's hard to know why this would return an error, as it's working in the test worksheet.

Comment: I understand this, and I'm following the exact worksheet as you've provided, but still NA

Comment: I just copied and pasted the data, used text-to-columns to convert it to `A1:C4` & `E1:H2`, and entered the formula `=INDEX($A$1:$C$4, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A$4=$E2)*($C$1:$C$4=F$1), 0), 2)` (an array formula) in `F2`, and it works fine. If I change the annotations in `col B`, the results update. My only other thought is: you don't want to actually copy the `{}`. In the cell, you type/paste `=INDEX($A$1:$C$4, MATCH(1, ($A$1:$A$4=$E2)*($C$1:$C$4=F$1), 0), 2)`, and then use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter the formula as an array formula. The `{}` will appear, but you don't want to actually type them.

Comment: @user47467: You need to be actively in the cell (in "edit" mode) and then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Just having the cell selected isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this
First create a new column on the first table `=B2&D2`

```
      A        B        C               D 
  1|           id       annotation      person_id    
  2|  11       1        yes             1            
  3|  12       1        no              2           
  4|  13       1        yes             3
```

And then on the second table use a formula like this

`=VLOOKUP(B16&C15;A2:C4;3;FALSE)`

```
      B    C    D    F 
14         1    2    3
15    1    yes  no   yes
16    2
```

Comment: You could also use index using the same logic